# Observable next operator usage confusion

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, angularfire, observable, angularfire2

I was going though a [codebase](https://github.com/rodrigoreal/ionic2-angularfire-login) for angularfire authentication and I could not understand the how this piece of code works.

Basically I am confused at how `observer.next()` is being used and in which context.

I understand that this method should return an observable but how does doing `.next()` on it helps.

I also looked at the documentation of `next()` [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takelast.html) its an alias for `takelast`.

I still fail to understand how this is working here.

```
loginWithFacebook() {
     return Observable.create(observer => {
     if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
        Facebook.login(['public_profile', 'email']).then(facebookData => {
        let provider = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(facebookData.authResponse.accessToken);
        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(provider).then(firebaseData => {
        this.af.database.list('users').update(firebaseData.uid, {
          name: firebaseData.displayName,
          email: firebaseData.email,
          provider: 'facebook',
          image: firebaseData.photoURL
        });
        observer.next();
      });
    }, error => {
      observer.error(error);
    });
  } else {
    this.af.auth.login({
      provider: AuthProviders.Facebook,
      method: AuthMethods.Popup
    }).then((facebookData) => {
      this.af.database.list('users').update(facebookData.auth.uid, {
        name: facebookData.auth.displayName,
        email: facebookData.auth.email,
        provider: 'facebook',
        image: facebookData.auth.photoURL
      });
      observer.next();
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.info("error", error);
      observer.error(error);
    });
  }
});
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: .next() is not called on the returned Observable. It's called on the observer. In short, it makes the created observable emit an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some addition to what @tagunp said with an example, here is a [link to jsbin](http://jsbin.com/dafopa/edit?html,js,console)

It triggers a message from the observer to the subscribers that values inside it have changed, `next()` & `error()` callbacks.

```
var source = Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
    Rx.Observable.range(0,5).subscribe(
      data => { 
        console.log(data)
        if(data > 2) {
        // conveys to the subscriber of source
        // that values has changed
        observer.next("greater than 2");
      }
    }
  )
})

source.subscribe(
  data => console.log(data)
)

Output:-

0
1
2
3
"greater than 2"
4
"greater than 2"
```

Answer (score 1):

The function returns an Observable, the next and errors will signal the subscriber to handle the call back.  Works like an email client, you can have multiple clients open and when the "next" email comes in they handle the message.

Comment: Thanks @targunp your answer surely helped. I have also attached a link jsbin in my answer do check.